# Why can't I insert data into local database (SQL Compact Edition) with C#?

Tags: c#, database

I am doing a project on Visual Studio. I am using a local database (empty sql server compact edition). I chose Dataset and created my table (Images). It has a primary autoincrement id column, and an nvarchar ImagePath column. I want to insert data in it and here is my code.

```
SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection();
con.ConnectionString = yeniApplicationDatabase.Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseEdaConnectionString;
con.Open();
using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Images (ImagePath) VALUES ('book')", con))
{
  com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I don't know why but this one doesn't give any error, the syntax(SQL) is fine. However, when I check the table data, it is still null. Here is the thing;

**In the same run**,
I execute that code, then
I execute another one which is select * from images...
It shows 'book'. But still, the table data is empty, and when I rerun it without inserting, only selecting from Images, it is gone again. I really don't understand what is going on. Why can't I put anything in my database?

I also added con.Close() but it still doesn't work.

Comment: closing the connection should complete the insert

Comment: i also did it but still it doesn't work. i dont know why.

Comment: I have updated the answer. If the query doesn't work on connection clode, check the link that I have mentioned in the answer which deals with commiting insert transactions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection();
con.ConnectionString =  yeniApplicationDatabase.Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseEdaConnectionString;
con.Open();
SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Images (ImagePath) VALUES ('book')", con);

com.ExecuteNonQuery();


com.Dispose();
con.Close();
```

Closing the connection should complete the insert.

**EDIT: update on the solution**

Which database file(.sdf) are you viewing to check whether the data has been inserted. check the content of the test table in the .sdf in the bin\Debug folder. I believe that your data is inserted properly in the database file which exist in bin\Debug folder.

Just found a similar question on stack overflow: [Why can't I insert a record into my SQL Compact 3.5 database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899310/why-cant-i-insert-a-record-into-my-sql-compact-3-5-database) and I firmly believe that your problem is exactly the same. you are checking the wrong database file.

Comment: this com is out of the using {..} block, it is con or com?

Comment: I tried con.Dispose() and con.Close() as you wrote but still it didn't add it.

Comment: I have updated the answer. try putting the code in a try catch block. and see if it gives you an error or gets executed successfully

Comment: i wrote try{ SqlCommand ..... } catch(Exception e ) and printed out the e but it didn't give any error.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Check the link that I have specified.

Comment: Which database file(.sdf) are you viewing to check whether the data has been inserted. check the content of the test table in the .sdf in the bin\Debug folder. I believe that your data is inserted properly in the database file which exist in bin\Debug folder

Comment: SqlCeTransaction tx = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted); line gave me an error. I don't know how to fix it :)

Comment: Check my answer again. I have updated it. you don;t have to use commit transaction. let me know if the update answer works

Comment: I checked the .sdf in the bin/Debug. I put sth in it, it was there, when I rerun without inserting, it was again empty.

Comment: If you find a solution to your problem, please updated it over here. I would like to know why your application is behaving this way.

Comment: This is going to be my senior project if I can manage it. However, it seems like I won't be able to graduate :)

Comment: what is your connection string?

Comment: yeniApplicationDatabase.Properties.Settings.Default.bokyeConnectionString; this one I am using. It is written Data Source=C:\Users\Eda\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\yeniApplicationDatabase\yeniApplicationDatabase\bokye.sdf

Comment: I also tried the one in bin/Debug but nothing changed. I need to ask a really stupid question. Do I have loose all the data after I close Visual Studio?

Comment: Change your connection string to C:\bokye.sdf and place the .sdf file in the c drive and try executing your application. It may sound lame, I wanna check whether its pointing to the right database.

Comment: No you dont. Once the transaction is executed, the changes have to be reflected in the database. Doesnt matter if you close visual studio. Also you need to open and close the connection each time you execute a sql statement. It is a good practice to do so

Comment: I cut and pasted bokye.sdf to where you said, made Data Souce = C:/bokye.sdf and run but it said Error 2 Unable to copy file "C:\Users\Eda\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\yeniApplicationDatabase\yeniApplicationDatabase\bokye.sdf" to "bin\Debug\bokye.sdf". Could not find file 'C:\Users\Eda\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\yeniApplicationDatabase\yeniApplicationDatabase\bokye.sdf'. yeniApplicationDatabase

Comment: cool. So what your application is doing is that each time you are running the insert statement, it is copying the blank database from the C:\Users\Eda\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\yeniApplicationDatabase\yeniApplicationDatabase\bokye.sdf' and moving it to the debug folder. (This is done as you are in the debug mode for the application). After that once your sql statement is executed, the data goes into the database in your debug folder. so everything works fine till now. the problem comes when you rerun the application. When you rerun the application, it copies the blank database agn

Comment: Now I will create a new database and make the tables. I wonder what will happen now.

Comment: How can I change that? I don't want it to copy the blank one. Please tell me there is a way. This is driving me crazy for a week!

Comment: and as it copies the blank database again into the debug folder, you cannot see the error. Do not cut and paste the database. Copy and paste the database, and after you have run the application, check the contents in the .sdf file in the C drive.

Comment: Give me 5 minutes and I will get back to you with the solution. Thanks

Comment: this is unbelievable!! It worked!! Thank you. I used C:\bokye.sdf as my connection string. And now I can see the table data even after I reopen Visual Studio! But I can't get the logic. Should I make two copies of my database? How can I fix this?

Comment: Change the connection string to back to what it was. click on the sdf file in the Solution Explorer and select Copy if newer. Try running the application and let me know if it works.

Comment: but first I need to clean the table. I forgot the sql command for that. I ll do it in a few mins first I need to truncate the table and find the sloution explorer :) I am very new at these :)

Comment: If I was helpful, accept this solution as your answer. Thus, I will be notified whether I was successful to resolve your problem. Thanks :)

Comment: I did it. It worked but it was already copy if newer. I made it exactly as it was before (the code), and now it works. I just didn't use Settings.bokyeConnectionString, I wrote it manually. This is weird.

Comment: This is weird, When I use con.ConnectionString = yeniApplicationDatabase.Properties.Settings.Default.bokyeConnectionString; there is still the same mistake, but when I use Data Source=C:\Users\Eda\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\yeniApplicationDatabase\yeniApplicationDatabase\bokye.sdf it adds it right. The first one doesn't place the data in the database. How come :S ?

Comment: Thank you very very very much. Can I give you like a thousand reputation points to thank you?

Comment: Thats because the yeniApplicationDatabase.Properties.Settings.Default.bokyeConnectionString is dynamic and depends whether your building it or publishing the application. It changes the connectionstring based on that. You can just accept the answer if it helped you and all the best for your application. I am sure you will do well. :)

Comment: I accepted the answer and I want to accept it a million times more. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I do not use Eclipse, but something you must watch out for in Visual Studio when debugging local databases is the Copy file property for the database file in Solution Explorer.

By default this property is "Copy", which means a copy of the database is put in the bin\debug folder of your project and the connection string is to the copy. If you change the copy, your original file is not changed and the changes are discarded when your debug session exits.

See if your IDE copies the database and inspect the connection string. Also how are you "checking the data table"? Are you using the same connection string? Are you doing this after the debug session ends?

Comment: I write an sql statement like (select * from images). this is how I check. Is it wrong? And how can I check whether it copies? Do I need to close and open the connection each time after I execute a query? And another question is that do I have to lose all the data after I close Visual Studio? I wrote Eclipse by mistake, sorry.

Comment: `select * from images` is fine so long as the connection string used for the select is the same as that used for the insert. Is it? Put a breakpoint on the SqlCeCommand object and check.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = c:\FullPath")
```

How to get full path: in solution explorer Right click on .Sdf  then get fullPath.