# SQL Compact Edition Insert C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I am trying to insert some values into a SQL CE database like this and nothing happens. What I do wrong?

```
string strConn = Properties.Settings.Default.SqlConnectionString;
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(strConn))
{
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("insert into CustTable(ID, Name) values (@Val1, @val2)", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val1", customer.ID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val2", customer.Name);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try doing a select statement instead of an insert statement if you can manage to get data into the database in any way, just to make sure you're talking to the (right) database in some form.

Comment: If I do an insert statement in SQL Server Management, it works just fine. But it dose not work in my application.

Comment: So do a select statement from your code to see if your code can at least *read* data from the database, if not write it.  Maybe the result will give you some clue.

Comment: It sure looks like you are connecting to a different database than the one you look at with SQL Server Management

Comment: @BlueMonkMN: Reading from the database works very well. I just tested it.

Comment: Then try doing everything you can think of in between what works and what doesn't work to narrow down the problem: Try a select statement with parameters like you have in your insert.  Try inserting and then selecting the data you just inserted all from code.  Try inserting data into that exact table from Management Studio, then selecting it from your program.  Try a select statement with the exact same parameter names and types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How are you "trying to insert some values..."? Are you running the app from Visual Studio? Why do you think "nothing happens"? Are you opening your original .sdf file after running your app?

Examine the Copy File property for the database file in Solution Explorer; is it "Copy"? That means Visual Studio will create a copy of the original database file in your bin folder and set the connection string to that path. All changes happen to the copy, and if you examine the original file it will be unchanged.

There is [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381080/) with the same problem; see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. The changes was made to the copy of the database wich is under the bin folder and I was looking into the original table :S

Comment: i have the same problem can you please tel;l me where to locate the copy property in using visual c# 2010 
kindly tell me detailed steps
thanks!

Comment: @user136640; select the .sdf file from the Solution Explorer window in VS, right-click and choose Properties, or select the Properties window.

Comment: Ok Dour i did it and changed it to do not copy when i use it it generates exception that file not found 
Please tell me how to do this as i use this DB file in more forms Also i want to export my project to setup file so giving the path myself is not suitable kindly solve my problem
Thanks!

Comment: @user136640; why are you changing it to "Do not copy"? Post a question, or join the Visual Studio chat.

Comment: I want to chat with you to explain you the detail of my problem Kindly Send Me link to chat with you or your skype ID

Comment: @user136640; click the "chat" link at the top of this window and search for Visual Studio, or try http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14809/visual-studio

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you forgot to [open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection.open%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) the connection first - try this:

```
    using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(strConn))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("insert into CustTable(ID,   Name) values (@Val1, @val2)",con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val1", customer.ID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val2", customer.Name);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It did not help eny. I dont get the values into my table :S

Comment: do you get an exception? If so can you show it? Otherwise - are you looking at the right database (the one your connection string specifies)?

Comment: @Man1: your code looks correct (with `con.Open();`). Are you getting any kind of exception thrown? Are your sure the code is actually executing?

Comment: Iam sure the code is executing and the thing is that I dont get eny exception at all. When I debug it throug Iam looking at the right database and all.

Comment: Perhaps you have some other code removing the rows? This is a common problem when you use a Transaction and then don't commit it, but that doesn't seem to be what you're doing.

Comment: No iam just doing a simple insert statement.

Comment: @Man1: You didn't use a read-only connection-string by chance? Something like `Data Source=MyData.sdf;File Mode=Read Only;...`

Comment: @BrokenGlass: No my datasource is not read only it looks like this. Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Customers.sdf

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(strConn))
{
    SqlCeParameter par;
    con.Open();
    SqlCeCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into CustTable(ID, Name) values (@Val1, @val2)";
    // Create the parameters
    par = new SqlCeParameter("@Val1", SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(par); 
    par = new SqlCeParameter("@Val2", SqlDbType.NChar, 50);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(par);
    // Set the values        
    cmd.Parameters["@Val1"].Value = customer.ID;
    cmd.Parameters["@Val2"].Value = customer.Name;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    // Dispose
    cmd.Dispose();
}
```