# Inserting records into SQL Compact Database

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce

I need to inject a row into sql compact database of the last gps reading. I don't need to obtain any information, just insert it.

I believe I have the connection to it from another post:

```
Dim connection As SqlCeConnection = New SqlCeConnection(String.Format("Data Source={0}", dbline))
```

but once I have the connection, how do quickly insert a row into a specific table? It's only 4 fields in the row.

Thanks!

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480351/sql-compact-edition-insert-c-sharp (your code is VB.Net but your tag is C#).

Comment: you're right, I usually program in C#, habit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=" + (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\DatabaseName.sdf;"));

SqlCeCommand sql = new SqlCeCommand("Insert into Table(Column1,Column2...) values (@Column1,@Column2...)", connection);
sql.Parameters.Add("@ParamName",ParamValue);
connection.Open();
sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```