# ConnectionString Database c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I am create a database utility and I seem to not be able to get my connectionstring correct.

```
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
   conn.ConnectionString =  
        "Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;" +
        "User Instance=true;" +
        "Integrated Security=true;" +
        "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|ConfigurationData.mdf;";
```

I believe this is in the correct format. As for the data source, my sql server is SQLExpress which runs sql server 2008 R2. My database is named ConfigurationData. Am I missing something?

When I run it, it opens the database - I assume it does since it does not through exception - but when I try inserting into a table, it does not actually insert it yet it executes the command.

```
conn.Open();
        try
        {

          SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Test " + "(id,number) " + "  VALUES(" + 10 + " , " + 12 + ")", conn);
          comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("Database is created successfully", "MyProgram");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            if ((conn.State == ConnectionState.Open))
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Most likely you're copying the .mdf file every time you build/debug, which overwrites the database the program is using with the copy you have in your solution. Can you verify this?

Comment: how do you check to see if it was inserted

Comment: I am new to databases and they way I check is that when I insert into the table, I place a breakpoint and open the table to check to see if it was inserted

Comment: Open SSMS and check in it if it is inserted or not

Comment: It did not arash, you think it might be the sql server?

Comment: Posted an  update. Answered a similar question a while back. Check below

Comment: 9 out of 10 times this is a case of acting and verifying on two different databases.  I would suggest you open SSMS and hand type the same insert statement

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
Just remembered that I had answered a similar question a while back. Check it out:

[Why can't I insert data into local database (SQL Compact Edition) with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381080/why-cant-i-insert-data-into-local-database-sql-compact-edition-with-c/5381298#5381298)

I don't think it is the connection string issue. But for your reference, a good site to refer to is http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/

You would need one of these:

Attach a database file, located in the data directory, on connect to a local SQL Server Express instance

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname;
Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

Attach a database file on connect to a local SQL Server Express instance

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\MyFolder\MyDataFile.mdf;Database=dbname;
Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

Using an User Instance on a local SQL Server Express instance
The User Instance functionality creates a new SQL Server instance on the fly during connect. This works only on a local SQL Server instance and only when connecting using windows authentication over local named pipes. The purpose is to be able to create a full rights SQL

Server instance to a user with limited administrative rights on the computer.

```
Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=true;
AttachDbFilename=C:\MyFolder\MyDataFile.mdf;User Instance=true;
```

To use the User Instance functionality you need to enable it on the SQL Server. This is done by executing the following command: sp_configure 'user instances enabled', '1'. To disable the functionality execute sp_configure 'user instances enabled', '0'.

Comment: It throws and error saying that the .\ unrecognized escaped sequence. would it be find if it was .\\?

Comment: Don't use "\\". Format the string like @"C:\...\"

Answer (score 0):

try (local) instead of dot, dot is not recognized in Win XP

```
conn.ConnectionString =  
        "Data Source=(local)\\SQLExpress;" +
        "User Instance=true;" +
        "Integrated Security=true;" +
        "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|ConfigurationData.mdf;";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the SqlConnectionStringBuilder class?:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.DataSource = @"(local)\SQLExpress";
builder.UserInstance = true;
builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
builder.AttachDBFilename = "|DataDirectory|ConfigurationData.mdf";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString());
```

The output:

```
    "Data Source=(local)\\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|ConfigurationData.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're SQL Statement isn't right also, and you should use parameters, but here is what you should have

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Test (id, number)  VALUES('" + 10 + " ', '" + 12 + "')", conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to do this is to add your connection string in web.config file as shown below:

Jus click on the properties of database on the database explorer. There you will find connectionstring in its properties. Jus add it in connectionstring below.

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnectionName" connectionString="your connection string" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Then in the page you can store it in string or directly refer to your connection as shown below:

```
Connection con=new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ToString();
```

and I suspect your insert statement is not properly declared.

Just try this:

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Test (id,number) VALUES('10' ,'12')", con);
```

That's all from my part... Hope it helped you..