# SQL command INSERT doesn't insert data into table, but debug shows it did (C#)

Tags: sql, winforms, c#-4.0, sql-server-ce

I can't get what is happening to my app. I'm using a SQL CE (.sdf file) to a local database (winform app) and when I debug, everything runs pretty well, I have in the end of it the message that my data was inserted well. But later on, when I check my databse, its empty.

What should I do?

This is my code:

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database\Livraria.sdf;");
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Livros (Codigo, ISBN, Titulo, Editora, Localizacao, Valor, QTD, Autor, AutorEspiritual, Data_) 
                            VALUES (@Codigo, @ISBN, @Titulo, @Editora, @Localizacao, @Valor, @QTD, @Autor, @AutorEspiritual, @Data_)";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Codigo", codigo);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISBN", isbn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titulo", titulo);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Editora", editora);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Localizacao", localizacao);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Valor", valor);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QTD", entradas);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Autor", autor);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AutorEspiritual", autorEspiritual);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data_", data_);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Livro adicionado com sucesso!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("O livro não foi adicionado.");
            }

            // Reset campos
            Codigo.Text = "";
            Titulo.Text = "";
            Editora.SelectedIndex = 0;
            Valor.SelectedIndex = 0;
            Localizacao.SelectedIndex = 0;
            Entrada.Text = "";
            Isbn.Text = "";
            Autor.SelectedIndex = 0;
            AutorEspiritual.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two databases.  You are inserting to one and looking for the results in another.

Or, you are starting a transaction, inserting but then not committing.

Comment: Thank you @Steve Wellens, I just saw this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899310/why-cant-i-insert-a-record-into-my-sql-compact-3-5-database that shows it, but now I have another question: when I run the application in not debug mode, my database will be the root one, right?

Comment: If your database is in the debug directory then when you run in release mode it will probably not be found.  You can also call: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", @"C:\MyData\");

Comment: I have a database also in my root folder (Database/database.sdf) I wonder de debug folder database is only for debug tests, after a publish my system it will run in my main database... at leadts it shoukd be like that o_0

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is to create a simple select statement first that gets record from you sqlce database.

```
if( has record//connected )
{
  //Proceed to your insert statement remove if else and use

  conn.Open();
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

  //then check your DB again 

}
else
{
//Problem on you connection string
}
```

Your sqlce database is located on your bin folder

Regards