# Write SQL queries using LINQ from linq object List

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a linq object and I want to write the query using linq.

please help me.

INPUT:

```
var tags = (from row in tempChildData.AsEnumerable()
                                join tagOrder in tupleInfoDataset.Tables["TagHierarchy"].AsEnumerable() on row.Field<Int64>("TAGID") equals tagOrder.Field<Int64>("TAGID")
                                join tagName in tupleInfoDataset.Tables["SequenceChoiceList"].AsEnumerable() on tagOrder.Field<Int64>("PARENTTAGID") equals tagName.Field<Int64>("TAGID")
                                join facet in tupleInfoDataset.Tables["FacetType"].AsEnumerable() on tagName.Field<string>("Tag_Name") equals facet.Field<string>("Facetname")
                                join tagIdInfo in schDataTogetTagid.AsEnumerable() on row.Field<string>("refTagName").Contains(":") ? row.Field<string>("refTagName").Split(':').Last():row.Field<string>("refTagName") equals tagIdInfo.Field<string>("TAGNAME")
                               where ( childList.Contains(row.Field<Int64>("TAGID")) && facet.Field<string>("FacetType").ToLower().Equals("ctype"))
                               select new
                               {
                                   Tagid = row.Field<Int64>("TAGID"),
                                   TagIdToInsert=tagIdInfo.Field<Int64>("TAGID"),
                                   MaxOccur = row.Field<string>("Maxoccurs"),
                                   MinOccur =Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(row.Field<string>("Minoccur"))),
                                   ParentTagId=tagOrder.Field<Int64>("PARENTTAGID"),
                                   Order=tagOrder.Field<Int64>("TAG_ORDER"),
                                   ParentTagname = tagName.Field<string>("Tag_Name"),
                                   FacetId=facet.Field<Int64>("FacetID")
                               }).ToList();


                    var parentTagID = (from tagIdInfo in tupleInfoDataset.Tables["Tuple"].AsEnumerable()
                                      where tagIdInfo.Field<Int64>("TAGID").Equals(key.Key)
                                      select tagIdInfo.Field<Int64>("ConceptID")).ToList();
                    long parentID =Convert.ToInt64(parentTagID[0]);
```

Now i want the query out of the above code as:

```
INSERT INTO TUPLE_MAP (TagId,ParentTagId,ParentTagname,MinOccur,MaxOccur,Order)
VALUES (TagIdToInsert,ParentTagId,ParentTagname,MinOccur,MaxOccur,Order)
```

Please help me I don't know how to write SQL queries using linq

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Here i want to insert data in the table from the "tags" objject list in the given query.. i am using sql compact 3.5..

Comment: Using the tags object  i want to write the Sql compact queries to insert the data in the database;INSERT INTO TUPLE_MAP (TagId,ParentTagId,ParentTagname,MinOccur,MaxOccur,Order)
VALUES (TagIdToInsert,ParentTagId,ParentTagname,MinOccur,MaxOccur,Order)
 where all the "tags" object data is used above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
using(var db=new DataContext("YourConnectionStringHERE"))
{
  db.TUPLE_MAP.InsertAllOnSubmit(tags.Select (t =>
  new TUPLE_MAP()
  {
       TagId=t.TagIdToInsert,
       ParentTagId=t.ParentTagId,
       ParentTagname=t.ParentTagname,
       MinOccur=t.MinOccur,
       MaxOccur=t.MaxOccur,
       Order=t.Order
  }));
  db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Or if you want to use the `parentID` then something like this:

```
using(var db=new DataContext("YourConnectionStringHERE"))
{
  db.TUPLE_MAP.InsertAllOnSubmit(tags.Select (t =>
  new TUPLE_MAP()
  {
       TagId=t.TagIdToInsert,
       ParentTagId=parentID,
       ParentTagname=t.ParentTagname,
       MinOccur=t.MinOccur,
       MaxOccur=t.MaxOccur,
       Order=t.Order
  }));
  db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

where db is your linq data context

Useful references:

- [How to: Insert Rows Into the Database (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386941.aspx)

**EDIT**

So if you are using the Compact database 3.5 then many something like this:

```
using (var conn =new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = test.sdf; Password ='pass'"))
{
        foreach (var tag in tags)
        {
            using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {

                cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO TUPLE_MAP (TagId,ParentTagId,ParentTagname,MinOccur,MaxOccur,Order)
                                    VALUES (@TagIdToInsert,@ParentTagId,@ParentTagname,@MinOccur,@MaxOccur,@Order)";

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TagIdToInsert", tag.TagIdToInsert);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParentTagId", tag.ParentTagId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParentTagname", tag.ParentTagname);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MinOccur", tag.MinOccur);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaxOccur", tag.MaxOccur);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order", tag.Order);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
    }
```

Useful references:

- [Why can't I insert a record into my SQL Compact 3.5 database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899310/why-cant-i-insert-a-record-into-my-sql-compact-3-5-database)
- [SqlCeCommand.Parameters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.parameters%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [SqlCeCommand Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.parameters%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx)

Comment: I want to use the query to insert data in Compact database 3.5 so Datacontext can't be use ..please reply thanx in advance..

Comment: Updated the answer take a look

Comment: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 13,Token in error = 24 ] im getting this error i tried but could not be resolved

Comment: Since there is Order column in my query which it is throwing error..How to handle that..please reply..im stuck here

Comment: Thanx alot its working..There was mistake from my end..I am extremely sorry for the inconvenience...Thanx a ton Sir..

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. @lokendrajayaswal : Remember to up vote the answers you think are good. That gives us all a warm fuzzy feeling :P

Answer (score 0):

Use linq Pad or sql profiler to see the generated SQL. 
You can also use visual studio for that purpose. In the debug mode,hold cursor on the variable "tags", you will be able to see the SQL.

Comment: This do not address the OPs question. He is not asking how to get the sql of the already written linq code. He is asking how to insert using linq

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Linq to SQL, if you are doing so you would have entity called Tuple_map in you xxxDataContext. Then you would just have to create object of that entity something like this....

```
using (XXXDataContext context = new XXXDataContext())
{
   Tuple_map obj = new Tuple_map();
   //Populate obj properties like obj.tabid = from objects you got it from above query
   context.Tuple_map.InsertOnSubmit(obj);
   context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: I want to make queries for sql compact 3.5 .. the above code does not work..please reply