# ado.net entity data model can't update database with savechange();

Tags: c#, ado.net, sql-server-ce

i am using visual c# 2010 , i using local database sql compact 3.5 . 
i want to insert to database using ado.net.

the problem is when i insert in application is success .but when i open table from , the record not updating at all.

```
cinemadataModel0 db = new cinemadataModel0();
MsEmployee tem1 = new MsEmployee();
tem1.EmployeeID = textBox1.Text;
tem1.EmployeeName = textBox2.Text;
tem1.EmployeePhone = textBox3.Text;
tem1.EmployeeAddress = textBox4.Text;
tem1.EmployeeEmail = textBox5.Text;

db.MsEmployees.AddObject(tem1);
db.SaveChanges();
viewemployee();
```

i don't know why my database is not update at all.

Comment: How did you determine that the database didn't change?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899310/why-cant-i-insert-a-record-into-my-sql-compact-3-5-database